# how to read data that is written from a communication Port?

Tags: python, c, uart

I try to make communication between my device and python code via COM4 a communication port:  pyserial communication.
So at first I try to send and write a hello then to read the output of my device, 
But the problem for me is how to read the hello that is sent firstly. I mean that I want to read the string  hello on COM4 from my device

```
 import serial
    ser = serial.Serial(
        port='COM4',\
        baudrate= 230400)  # open serial port
    print(ser.name)         # check which port was really used
    #ser.write(b'hello\n')     # write a string
    #str=ser.readline()
    while True:
        print(ser.read(30).decode())
    ser.close()             # close ports
```

The code of my device is written in C language.

I would be very grateful if you could guide me please.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the problem is exactly. Where do you want to read the string "hello"? On your device? Or does the device send a string "hello" that you want to read in Python? Please make your question more specific.

Comment: I send the string hello, my device is already able to write it, however how could I recover that string from the COM4, by using my device in order to read it. is it clear now?

Comment: So you want to read the data on COM4 from your device? If that is the case, this is not a Python question, but a C question (you say that your device is running a C program). Unfortunately, I'm not a C expert and don't have a quick answer for that problem...

Comment: @Sven Feestersen, thank you very much i must edit my question

Comment: Please add tag:python

Comment: I don't receive any answer, there is no one  that can help me please.

Answer (score 0):

This process differs based on the operating system.  Here's a good library that supports Linux and Windows:
http://www.teuniz.net/RS-232/